# How to convert date format from yyyy-mm-dd to dd MMM yyyy

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C#.I'm facing difficulty in converting date format

**I want to convert the date format 2020-02-02 to 02 Mar 2020**

I wrote the below function in c#,but it is very lengthy code

Is there any built-in function available in c# to reduce code

Is there a simple way to do this?

```
public string ConvertToOutputDate(string input) {
    // 2020-02-02
    string year = input.Substring(0, 4);
    string month = input.Substring(5, 2);
    string day = input.Substring(8, 2);

    string overall = day;

    switch (month) {
    case("01"):
        overall += " Jan";
        break;
    case ("02"):
        overall += " Feb";
        break;
    case ("03"):
        overall += " Mar";
        break;
    case ("04"):
        overall += " Apr";
        break;
    case ("05"):
        overall += " May";
        break;
    case ("06"):
        overall += " Jun";
        break;
    case ("07"):
        overall += " Jul";
        break;
    case ("08"):
        overall += " Aug";
        break;
    case ("09"):
        overall += " Sep";
        break;
    case ("10"):
        overall += " Oct";
        break;
    case ("11"):
        overall += " Nov";
        break;
    case ("12"):
        overall += " Dec";
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("> That Month doesn't Exist!: " + month);
    }
    overall += " " + year;

    return overall;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to convert date format simply:

```
public string ConvertToOutputDate(string input)
{
         return DateTime.Parse(input).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
}
```

And also you can play with other date formats by passing them as args to ToString() method.

Answer (score 0):

Got the Answer

```
public string ConvertToOutputDate(string input)
        {
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(input);
            string newDate = date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
            return newDate;
        }
```